# Rake routes error with devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

My routes.rb is look like this.

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions]
as :user do
  get 'signin' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
  post 'signin' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
  delete 'signout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
end
```

When i have run `rake routes` i got the error

```
undefined method `as' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0xa954f20>
/home/ramkishan/vijay_work/kirana/config/routes.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: if i've got you, you're trying to skip sessions scope from routes?

Comment: And i need to change the route of devise/session https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes

Comment: try to use 'devise_scope' instead of 'as', if it doesn't help, try to bundle and restart your server

Answer (score 0):

No need to use **as**,

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions] do
  get '/signin'   => "devise/sessions#new",       :as => :new_user_session
  post '/signin'  => 'devise/sessions#create',    :as => :user_session
  get '/signout'  => 'devise/sessions#destroy',   :as => :destroy_user_session
end
```

should do.